# Why Won't My Path Show Direction (With "Show Normal" on)?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm at a loss here. I have enabled the Normals under Overlays. Can anyone think of a reason my path direction won't make an appearance?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/deh27u3ri3sdija/Curve%20Normals%20Where.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: that's odd. can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: is your path very large so you can't see the normals?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I have added the project file. Please let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: @Blunder no the path is the default size, not scaled at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D curves have no Normals. Change the curve to 3D under the curves *Object Data Properties*

[image]

Comment: Ha, I hoped it would be this simple!  Thanks a lot for that ;)